# Using VBS Script in AAE and getting 1024 Expect Statement

Tags: vba, vbscript, automationanywhere

I am new to coding in VBS and all the time I am getting 1024 Expect Statement Error in my VBScript. If anyone could point me where is a mistake I would be gratefull.

```
Dim Path
Dim BeginDate
Dim EndDate
Path = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
BeginDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(1)
EndDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(2)
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)
objExcel.Visible = True
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("Q3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("P3").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & BeginDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
```

Till filtering part everything goes correct. When I try to run filtering part as a Macro in Excel it works but when I am implementing it into Script it throws me an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In VBScript, you don't have to mention the name of the parameters while calling a function/method. You just need to pass the values. The parameters names are required in excel-vba, not in VBScript.

So, try replaying,

```
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter Field:=8, Criteria1:="<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("Q3").AutoFilter Field:=17, Criteria1:="<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("P3").AutoFilter Field:=16, Criteria1:=">=" & BeginDate, Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=" & EndDate
```

with

```
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter 8,"<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("Q3").AutoFilter 17,"<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("P3").AutoFilter 16,">=" & BeginDate,1,"<=" & EndDate
```

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-autofilter-method-excel) to the Autofilter Method

[Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/xlautofilteroperator-enumeration-excel) to the enumerated constant `xlAnd`

Comment: As I assumed 
    <Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter 8,"<>">
this line is supposed to throw away all blank cells from the scope, but I am getting type mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

VBScript can't handle named parameters. Change the last lines to

```
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter 8, "<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("Q3").AutoFilter 17, "<>"
Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("P3").AutoFilter 16, ">=" & BeginDate, xlAnd, "<=" & EndDate
```

and it'll hopefully get you a step closer. You might need to define xlAnd and other constants as well.

Answer (score 1):

`VBScript`, as the other answers state, does not handle the named parameters.

Therefore it doesn't know what you mean by `Worksheets`.  They will need to be fully qualified as references belonging to the parent `objWorkbook` object.

```
objWorkbook.Worksheets("PO Buy Update").Range("H3").AutoFilter 8, "<>"
```

will work just fine.  You will need to replace any and all excel named values (such as `xlAnd`) with the enumerated value equivalent, or declare them as constants and set the value to match the enumerated value if you want to use the named parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your answers and pointing me, my mistakes. My final solution is below

```
Dim Path
Dim BeginDate
Dim EndDate
Path = WScript.Arguments.Item(0)
BeginDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(1) 
EndDate = WScript.Arguments.Item(2) 
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)
Set c=objWorkBook.Worksheets("PO Buy Update") // Attached WorkbookSheet(name) into variable and then specified which row, column is a header 
objExcel.Visible = True
c.cells(3,8).AutoFilter 8, "<>"           
c.cells(3,17).AutoFilter 17, "<>"
c.cells(3,16).AutoFilter 16, ">=" & BeginDate, 1, "<=" & EndDate
```

I believe my main problem was that I have header in third row and when I did not specified that Script was searching for filtering option in first row.

Once again thanks for your time !